# ANR with high iowait in android

Tags: android, iowait

I am running youtube application and getting an ANR and device is responsive slow.

And I am getting iowait 64%

```
E ActivityManager: 98% TOTAL: 12% user + 20% kernel + 64% iowait + 0% irq + 1.1% softirq
```

So how we can identify causing application for iowait or it can handle by IO scheduling at kernel side.